# Does "eff" mean to describe in words?

Tags: meaning, etymology, roots

If one dissects the word "ineffable", there are three main roots

- `in` - not
- `able` - able to be done
- `eff`

The meaning of the root `able` implies that some part of the word before it must refer to an action. Given that `in` is solely and adverb in this case, that would, by default, make `eff` a verb. Knowing that `eff` is a verb with a meaning antonymic to the word as a whole, I assume that it means something to the effect of "to describe in words"

However, I have not yet found a dictionary that acknowledges this. They have acknowledged "effable",but not "eff". Is it simply a quirk of our language that the word is never used, or has my logic failed me somewhere?

Comment: eff has no meaning in English. We imported the word "effable" (effabilis) and "ineffable" (ineffabilis) as units from Latin, and only later* generalized the common pieces "-able" and "in-" to the meanings you find in dictionaries. "effa-" (from Latin effari, which as you surmise is related to speech) has never been used as an independent root in English. (* "later" meaning independently. They might have been active prior to importing the effable pair.)

Comment: This is Off Topic General Reference, because any reasonable dictionary will give the [etymology of "ineffable"](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=ineffable)

Comment: @FumbleFingers: You mean 'Eff Topic'.

Comment: @Mitch: No I effing well dont!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root of *[ineffable](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=ineffable)* is not an English word **eff,* but rather a Latin word, *effari* “utter” = *ex + fari* “speak out.”

Answer (score 2):

Ineffable is from in + effor + ablis (not + speak + able). Effor means 'to speak' or 'to say out' or 'to utter'.

'Eff' doesn't necessarily have any meaning in English, or at least not in modern english where 'effable' and 'ineffable' are fairly archaic, but as a component the meaning is there.